# Date_field in Rails, how to customize

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use `date_field` or `date_select`, user can still select date from January or February (start_year is the only thing I can specify). 
I obviously want user to be able to choose a date which isn't earlier than today. Is it possible to do it in Rails?

Comment: please add code for getting better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following with a simple rails `select` form helper.

```
<%= f.select :month, Date.today.month..12%>
<%= f.select :year, Date.today.year..x.years.from_now.year %>
```